# Sub Query with SUM and DISTINCT

Tags: sql

I have the below query for which I want to det the distinct districts and the sum of how many properties there are for each one.

I can't remember how to do the sub query.

```
SELECT DISTRICT, PROPREF

FROM TBL_PROPERTY 

WHERE  (CONTRACT = 'ma2') AND 
        (LASTSERVICEDATE <= DATEADD(HH,23,CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/05/2009', 103))) AND 
        (SERVICESTATUS = 'SERVICED')) AS Sub1


GROUP BY DISTRICT, OFFICE, PROPREF
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
select DISTRICT, count(PROPREF)
from TBL_PROPERTY
where CONTRACT = 'ma2'
    and LASTSERVICEDATE <= DATEADD(HH,23,CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/05/2009', 103))
    and SERVICESTATUS = 'SERVICED'
group by DISTRICT
```

If you also wanted it broken out by office, you'd add OFFICE to the select and group by clauses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PROPERTY_COUNT ...
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

just figured it out sorry if anyone responded!! Also forgot to take office out i think which i got rid of in end.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DISTRICT), SUM(services) AS TOTALSERVICES

FROM 

(SELECT DISTRICT, COUNT(PROPREF) AS Services

FROM TBL_PROPERTY 

WHERE  (CONTRACT = 'ma2') AND 
        (LASTSERVICEDATE <= DATEADD(HH,23,CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/05/2009', 103))) AND 
        (SERVICESTATUS = 'SERVICED')
GROUP BY DISTRICT, propref

) as sub1

GROUP BY DISTRICT, services
```